# Clone code from one particular revision to the tip of that branch

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branch, bitbucket, cloning

I am using mercurial version control in Bitbucket.I have been working on a project with a **Default** branch and **Product** branch.Product branch started at revision number **10**.It's not merged with default at any point. Now I need codes from the beginning of Product branch(ie; revision 10) to the tip of that branch to create a new repository. Is this possible. I tried

```
hg clone https://NAME@bitbucket.org/TEAM/REPO -r BRANCH_NAME
```

But I got the code from revision 1 to the tip of Product Branch.What I needed was from revision 10 to the tip. Is this possible.Please give me a solution.

Comment: This should not happen under the premises you are describing.

Comment: @Ringding  Actually the situation is a little different.But the basic idea is that I need to clone one branch from one particular revision to the tip of that.I posted it like above for clear understanding ie;not to get the question too Complex.

Comment: You will get all changesets that are needed to get all the changesets of that branch. This will include all changesets on other branches that have been merged into that branch. You cannot discard history using clone.

Comment: If the branches are actually separate, i.e., have no connection whatsoever, then you can do what you want, exactly like you stated you tried to. This is a rather unusual situation though.

Comment: @Ringding  But the isssue is that I can get only revision 1 to the tip of that branch.I want to neglect the base changes upto revision 10.

Comment: This is not possible if they are ancestors of tip.

Comment: @Ringding..Upto revision 10  are not ancestors of tip.The Product Branch is completely independent. It was maintained in the same repo for easy management.But now as its implementations are increasing, its difficult to be kept together.Thats why I requested for such a solution.